# Group by clause in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>11.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1994</YEAR>
  </CD>  
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tylor</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>....and so on
```

I want to write a query in xslt to print the no.of cd's per country. Here's how i approached it.

- I sorted the cd's based on country in ascending order.
- then in for-each loop for every country i tried counting the no.of cd's but
  its printing some weird numbers.

Please help me out in figuring this.

I'm using **XSLT 1.0**

**EDIT:** ok so i read about muenchian grouping and tried the following code but im still not getting the desired output. Here's the code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:key name="country" match="//CD" use="COUNTRY" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <center>
    <h2>Print the no. of records for each country.</h2>
    </center>
      <xsl:call-template name="query5"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="query5">

    <table align="center" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Records</th>
      </tr>

      <xsl:for-each select="//CD[generate-id() = generate-id(key('country',COUNTRY)[1])]">
        <xsl:sort select="COUNTRY"/>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="COUNTRY"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('country', COUNTRY)">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(//CD)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But im still not getting desired output. Please advice

Comment: You'll save time for those who try to answer your question, and be more likely to get a helpful answer, if you provide (a) some of the actual XSLT code you tried, (b) some of the output ("weird numbers") you're getting, and (c) the expected output (non-weird numbers).

Comment: Search for "Muenchian grouping" - this is the standard approach to grouping problems in XSLT 1.0.  Essentially you define a _key_ to group the `CD` elements by `COUNTRY`, then use the Muenchian trick to iterate over the list of _distinct_ country names and count the number of matches in the key for each one.

Comment: Made edits. @IanRoberts

Comment: @LarsH: Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: I can take a look. Can you show us the output you're getting, and the output you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing it myself, here's what I would change:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="key('country', COUNTRY)">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(//CD)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

to

```
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('country', COUNTRY))" />
```

Explanation:

- You have the outer loop doing a proper Muenchian-grouped "for each country"; or more precisely, "for each CD that is the first CD for its respective country". (Good job applying the Muenchian technique BTW, if that's your first time.)
- Inside that loop, you're asking XPath to count the number of nodes in the set returned by the key for the COUNTRY of the current CD.

Bonus: I like to name keys following [Jeni Tennison's example](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), 'Xs-by-Y', where X is the type of thing returned by the key, and Y is the type of value passed to the key (i.e. what is referenced by the `use=` attribute). This makes it much easier for me to think straight when defining the key and when using it, so that I don't get confused between what the `key()` function takes and what it returns. So in your case, naming the key `'CDs-by-COUNTRY'` would make the code more readable and help prevent mistakes.

You might choose a different key naming convention, but it helps to have something that makes the identity of the key vs. the value explicit. Especially if you're not doing type checking.

Comment: Thank you that modification solved the answer and yes this is the first time i used that grouping